# How to send a https request from geokettle

Tags: javascript, pentaho, etl, geokettle

I am using geokettle tool and while ETL operation is performing I want to send a request after
extracting from source and before loading it into target.
Please help me.

Comment: you mean web services look up.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a quick check I found that I could send an HTTPS request when the HTTPS site is not using a self signed certificate, otherwise I get an error.

[image: Example GeoKettle transform testing HTTPS resources]